# Сортировка объектов

Tags: python, сортировка

Есть список объектов:

```
[<imagemanager.util.DirImageItem object at 0xaa1bf8c>, <imagemanager.util.DirImageItem object at 0xa8f984c>, ...]
```

Если посмотреть внутренности одного из объектов `items[0].__dict__` , то вот что увидим:

```
{
'fields':
 {
  'attribs': 'RW',
  'modifed': '2007-05-15 11:54',
  'name': 'kl9e2itd07xcayohm5rq.png',
  'created': '2010-02-22 13:36',
  'url': '/media/news/kl9e2itd07xcayohm5rq.png',
  'custom': {'width': 100, 'editable': False, 'thumbnail': True, 'height': 100},
  'path': '/media/news/kl9e2itd07xcayohm5rq.png',
  'type': 'png',
  'size': 435
 },
'filename': <dUrl /media/news/kl9e2itd07xcayohm5rq.png>}
```

Такое содержит каждый объект, их нужно сортировать по дате `created`. Сортировать по принципу от нового к старому.

Пытался так:

```
items = sorted(items, key=lambda k: k.fields['modifed'])
```

Увы, ничего не изменилось.

Подскажите, что не так делаю, или другой способ сортировать объекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует использовать:

```
items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x['fields']['modifed'])
или
items.sort(key=lambda x: x['fields']['modifed'])
```

Аналогично для created, заменить 'modifed'.

Comment: Не так не прокатывает. Так пробовал, ошибка. Именно так как я написал если обращаться, то получить можно данные, в данном случае получим "2007-05-15 11:54"

Comment: приведите текст ошибки

Comment: 'DirImageItem' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: может тогда получиться через поле dict'a? : 

    x.__dict__['fields']['modifed']

Comment: Так ошибки нет, но ничего с файлами не происходит, все в таком же порядке.
Скажите, ну вообще эта схема правильная? Возможно просто на том этапе они сортируются, но дальше при выводе это теряет смысл.
Завтра исследую на каждом этапе сортируются ли объекты.

Comment: можете попробовать вывести все элементы непосредственно после сортировки, вывести только то поле по которому сортировали. Через одну строчку порядок сортировки точно не должен был измениться )

Comment: В общем все варианты правильные. Прошлый программист назначал всем дату и время одно и тоже. Исправил, всё заработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Такое содержит каждый объект, их нужно сортировать по дате **created**.
>
> items = sorted(items, key=lambda k: k.fields['**modifed**'])

Так по `created` или по `modified`?

Так-же убедитесь, что `items[n].k.fields['created']` для всех элементов возвращает именно то, что вы ожидаете. В остальном все правильно.

Comment: Вывел все данные, понял что они одинаковые. Выше написал почему. А так любой из вариантов был верен. Спасибо.